# What's the simplest way to get user Groups from WAAD?

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've got AngularJS and Web.API WAAD authentication up and running. For client side I use great library [ADAL.JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). For backend I use [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/). This part went quite smooth.

Now I want to implement authorization based on roles (which will be mapped to WAAD groups). Groups are not included in authentication token so I must ask Azure Graph API for them. I saw various ways to do it, using custom claims providers, adding web services to project, etc. Some examples already providing mapping between groups and roles to use in `[Authorize]` attribute.

But what is just the simplest example of how to get a list of group ids/names from WAAD providing User ID or username, when I'm already authenticated?

Also, is there any way to get this data in JS to use in Angular frontend, or should I create an API service which Angular should call for roles info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the non-JS case, the simplest way of getting groups in the token is by opting in. Download your application’s manifest, locate the “groupMembershipClaims” entry, change its value to “SecurityGroup” or “All”, upload back the manifest. 
However note that this won't work for your scenario, because it uses the implicit grant - here the token is returned in an URI fragment, hence a big token would risk blowing past the URL length limits of the browser.
You can always request groups to the Graph and make it available to your frontend via custom action on your API, but from what you wrote you are already familiar with that. Let me discuss the matter here - if there's a simpler route to make this work in SPAs, I'll get back to this thread.
HTH
V.
Update: I verified and in the implicit grant case you will receive groups always via the overage claim. Please refer to https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/tree/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet - it will show you how to process the overage claim to retrieve groups. All you need to do is apply the same guidance to a web API instead, and if you need to make the info available to the client expose one or more actions doing so.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I hope I'll be able to try it at the beginning of next week. If not, then I'll get back to it in January and let know if it worked.