# Access Azure Graph API on behalf of application rather than user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

Following on from my previous question: [Group claims with Azure AD and OAuth2 implicit grant in ADAL JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762551/group-claims-with-azure-ad-and-oauth2-implicit-grant-in-adal-js), I've have things set up so users can authenticate using Azure/ADAL JS and then I use the their token to access the Azure Graph API on behalf of that user. This works well and I'm able to get their user and group information.

However, we now have a use case where another system will log into our application in the application's context rather than as an individual user. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly but I've got a second Azure AD Application with a client key that authenticates by [requesting a token from the AAD API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/azure/dn645543.aspx). I can get a token and pass that to our application. However, I can no longer use that token to access the Azure Graph API on behalf of that user (which is now an application).

Firstly, is this actually possible to do or am I attempting the impossible?

If it is possible, what do I have to do differently to get it to work? Is it just permissions in the Azure application or do I need to do it differently in code?

The code I use for accessing the Graph API on behalf of a user (with exception handling and null checks removed) is:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential("clientId", "key");
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(((BootstrapContext)identity.BootstrapContext).Token);

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCredential, userAssertion);
return result.AccessToken;
```

The exception I get is `AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the {directory ID of my main application} directory` with an error of `invalid_grant`.

I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong as I believe all the Azure applications are configured correctly, well they are for user authentication at least. I also applied the same application and delegated permissions to my second Azure AD (client) application that other directories need for user auth.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Update: system overview/configuration

So it seems that I didn't provide enough context around how the system is configured so let me attempt to address that here.

We have an enterprise SaaS application running in Azure (let's call this *our application*). It has an "application" in Azure AD (let's call this *our AAD application* to avoid confusion). This is a multi-tenant AAD application and users authenticate using OAuth2 via AAD.

Being an enterprise application, our customers all have their own Azure AD (which may or may not be synced to an on-premise AD) (let's call this *their AAD*). When configuring their system to work with *our application*, we have a Global Administrator from *their AAD* grant *our AAD application* consent to the following permissions for Windows Azure Active Directory (using the admin consent grant):

- Application permissions:

  - Read directory data
- Delegated permissions:

  - Access the directory as the signed-in user
  - Read directory data
  - Sign in and read user profile

When the users browse to *our application*, they will be redirected to Azure for authentication. After being authenticated (whether by *their AAD* or via an on-premise AD connected to *their AAD*), any API calls made via the web app will include a Bearer token. The first time we see each Bearer token, we use it to get a new token for the Azure Graph API (On Behalf Of the user) and query the Graph API for user details and group memberships. This all works when users authenticate via a UI with their own user account.

What we are looking to do now allow our customers to have another downstream application (*their downstream application*) get its own Bearer token to use *our application*. This time there is no user so we're looking at the [client credentials grant flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/azure/dn645543.aspx). To do this, our customer now has their own AAD application (*their AAD application*) which is in *their AAD* (which has already been granted consent as above). *Their downstream application* can get a Bearer token to access *our application*. However, when we try to get a token for the Azure Graph API (On Behalf Of *their downstream application*), it fails with the error message I pasted above.

#### Update 2

*Another member of my team has done some investigation and these are his findings.*

> I've been through the process manually by looking at what the SDK does behind the scenes
>   and doing all the requests manually to better allow it to be reproduce what we are doing.
>
> So the calling service (which is a web application setup inside a Azure Active Directory)
>   obtains an OAuth token from Azure, i.e.
>
> ```
> POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
>
> grant_type      client_credentials
> client_id       (the client ID of the calling service application in the AD)
> client secret   (the key configured in the calling service application in the AD)
> resource        (the client ID of our web service)
> ```
>
> And we get a valid token which contains a `appid`, `tid`, `oid`, `iss`, etc. but no `name`,
>   `upn`, etc. (since it is not a user but an application).
>
> So then we want to look up the details of the service principal from the Graph API, and we
>   request to get a Graph API token on behalf of the application, i.e.
>
> ```
> POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
>
> grant_type            urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
> client_id             (our web service application client ID)
> client_secret         (our web service application client key)
> resource              https://graph.windows.net
> assertion             (the token that was sent by the calling client service, obtained by the process above)
> requested_token_use   on_behalf_of
> scope                 openid
> ```
>
> Which is basically what happens when we call the following code (extracted from the SDK code)
>
> ```
> var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
> var clientCredential = new ClientCredential("clientId", "key");
> var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(((BootstrapContext)identity.BootstrapContext).Token);
>
> var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCredential, userAssertion);
> return result.AccessToken;
> ```
>
> All it returns is:
>
> ```
> {
>   "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the <customer tenant id> directory.\r\nTrace ID: <removed>\r\nCorrelation ID: <removed>\r\nTimestamp: 2015-10-08 06:37:58Z",
>   "error_codes": [ 50034 ],
>   "timestamp": "2015-10-08 06:37:58Z",
>   "trace_id": "<removed>",
>   "correlation_id": "<removed>"
> }
> ```
>
> So I guess the question is, can we get a graph API token on behalf of a caller with a bearer token,
>   if the caller is an web/native application and not an actual user?

Comment: Is your application present in this 2nd Azure AD?

Comment: Yes. I granted consent with a Global Administrator as I normally would for any other directory I was using for user auth.

Comment: Hi Richard, We took a look at your question, but are very confused at the setup, so we are having a hard time providing answers to your questions. Can you please go into a bit more detail about the specific applications in your scenario (how many are there, do you have a multi-tier system, who is acting as a client, what resources are they contacting, and in what context).

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I have edited my question to provide more detail around our configuration and how the pieces fit together. I hope this helps clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for the clarification, it helps. Have you had a chance to review some of the documentation we have on the On-Behalf-Of scenario? You can find some [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) and we have a sample that should work end to end [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-OnBehalfOf-DotNet). Can you try using this sample to test your current configuration?

Comment: That sample works because it pops up a sign in window and a _user_ types in their credentials. I'm talking about the scenario where there is no interactive sign in window, but rather a _service-to-service_ call using a secret key. I haven't yet look at modifying the sample to handle the sign in this way instead. I'll try that tomorrow unless you have another sample that does the same but with service-to-service auth?

Comment: It turns out that sample doesn't work for me. I get an error saying `AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.` when the client tries to authenticate. I tried modifying it to do the service-to-service auth but without actually having the user auth working, it's a bit hard to know where the issues are.

Comment: I got user auth working by getting my bearer token separately and sending an API request directly to the TodoListService (without the TodoListClient) and got the Graph API to return my user details. I then tried app auth by getting a bearer token via the client credentials grant flow API I referred to above but I get the exact same error I mentioned in my question. I'm wondering if it is the user assertion (lines 135-137 of TodoListController) part because the UPN and email claims don't exist for applications. Is there a different username I should be using in the user assertion for apps?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Did you get a chance to look into this yet?

Comment: @RichardPickett Did you get it running? We're encountering the same issues.

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof No never got it working. We had to work around the issue at that time (by disabling Graph API lookups for application logins). One day I will get back to it so I'm hoping someone finds a solution before then.

Comment: I've made it work, I'll post my findings as an answer

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to log in the Microsoft Graph API without user credentials. You can setup a `ClientCredential` with a `Client ID` and the `Client Secret`. With that `ClientCredential` you can authenticate an `AuthenticationContext` and retrieve an access token. The access token gives you access to the Graph API.

**Code Sample:**

```cs
string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenant = "<your-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
string clientId = "<your-clientId>";
string appKey = "<your-application-key>"; // Or Client Secret
string resourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientCredential);
string response;

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var resultApi = await client.GetAsync("/v1.0/users");
    response = await resultApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't address the core problem I identified in my question. This code works fine when you're accessing your application's _own_ directory. However, in my case, my application is attempting to access the _user's_ directory. Users will authenticate against a different AAD. This is all possible with user accounts as there is an _on behalf of_ token. However, it doesn't seem possible to get an _on behalf of_ token for another application (in another directory) to access that other directory.