# Azure AD: How to get group information in token?

Tags: adal, azure-active-directory

We have application developed in MEAN stack. We are using [adal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) library for azure ad authentication. As per the [documentation and sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular/)

> Adal.js uses the OAuth implicit flow to communicate with Azure AD. You
> must enable the implicit flow for your application.

However when we enable implicit flow, Azure AD **DOES NOT** include group information in the token. The issue has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762551/group-claims-with-azure-ad-and-oauth2-implicit-grant-in-adal-js) in detail and confirmed by @vibronet

Question
Azure AD functionalities have been changing almost everyday, so are the above answers still valid? Do we still have to enable implicit flow of our application? I want to get group information in token *(i dont want to use graph api as a solution.)*

another reason i am asking this question because i **disabled** the implicit flow and user was still able to access the application. However i still don't see **group** information in the token.

Comment: Did you enable group claims in the application manifest? To avoid using GraphAPI, how will you guarantee that your users will never have more groups than the max allowed in a token?

Comment: Assuming this is also you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b49109b-b98a-4b54-b644-43d623a7d36a/azure-ad-jwt-token-is-missing-group-information?forum=WindowsAzureAD, I see you have. Have you looked at the raw `id_token` (e.g. with something such as jwt.io)?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret Yes thats me.  Not sure how jwt.io would help me here if azure never include that information in the token. Also we are using "passport-azure-ad" on server that parse & validates the token

Comment: In the forum post you proposed that *perhaps* Azure AD is not returning the groups. Looking at the raw token would allow you to confirm if the it contains the groups (and thus it is the library that is dropping them). It appears you have confirmed that it is not.

Comment: Yes i verified the JWT token, i have configured groupMembershipClaims" to "SecurityGroup". When i do that i get extra property "hasgroup=true" but not actual group ids

Comment: @LP13 did you managed to find a solution for this? I also get hasgroups but no groups information.

Comment: @Sid we stopped using Azure AD :)

Answer (score 7):

Azure AD JWT **does** emit security groups in implicit flow.
In Application Registration manifest, set `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`,

Then in your server:

```
var groups = new List<string>();
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims
    .Where(t => t.Type == "groups")
    .ForEach(g => groups.Add(g.Value));
```

no need for GraphApi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims