# How to get memberId from Azure token_id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to check whether authenticated user is present in the group or not,
So we need to make a call as below:

POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/isMemberOf?api-version

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "groupId": "5e624f44-d38d-4943-b07c-2bad078f52ff",

"memberId": "ea59e4d3-a7a1-4b5b-b65f-a25fcc0c0f99"
}

From where do we get the memeberId from the this.adalService.userInfo after user is authenticated. Below is the response I got, from the below response is there any property belong to memeberId.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the user's object id. In this case it is the `oid` claim. In your image: `this.adalService.userInfo.profile.oid`.

More info on claims in ID tokens can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims#idtokens

> oid
>
> Object ID
>
> Contains a unique identifier of an object in Azure AD. This value is immutable and cannot be reassigned or reused. Use the object ID to identify an object in queries to Azure AD.

That function can be used to check group membership for users, groups, contacts or service principals. In all cases the memberId should be the objectId of the corresponding object.

Though it seems you are receiving member groups in the `groups` claim, why not use that?

Comment: Hi Juunas, Thanks for the solution, Some time, instead of group, we get hasGroup=true. please check this link: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/239 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780567/azure-ad-how-to-get-group-information-in-token#44844610).

Comment: Right, if a user has too many groups then you would have to get them from the API.

Comment: Hi Juunas, I am facing the above error "your access token has expired please renew it before the request", currently I am not passing any Authorization Bearer token, do we need to pass Bearer token also?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the access token for the API as `Authorization: Bearer token-here`.

Comment: Hi Juunas, Above attached the image of POST man, I tried using token with POST and GET, getting error "Access Token missing or malformed", please help me on this, is this post or GET, let me know if any thing is wrong

Comment: Hi Juunas, I think I am passing token_id as Bearer , how do I get graph api access token to pass to Bearer token

Comment: You can find an answer to that question very easily from the samples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples